# Spring Boot Failed to use @Value for injection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot version `<version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>`

### Error goes as follows:

Description:

> Parameter 2 of constructor in
>   `com.shawn.foodrating.service.impl.AdServiceImpl` required a bean of
>   type `java.lang.Integer` that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'java.lang.Integer' in your configuration.

### My Code:

```java
@Service
@Transactional(rollbackOn = Exception.class)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AdServiceImpl implements AdService {
 private AdRepository repository;
 private FileService fileService;
 @Value("${app.ad.DefaultPageSize}")
 private Integer DEFAULT_PageSize;
 @Value("${app.ad.ImagePath}")
 private String AD_IMAGE_PATH;
 @Value("${app.ad.ImageUrl}")
 private String AD_IMAGE_URL;
```

Load property file

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
public class FoodRatingApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FoodRatingApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Not Sure what is wrong with it.

Comment: can you show the complete code of `AdServiceImpl` and also annotate that class with `@NoArgConstructor`

Answer (score 5):

When you use Lombok's `@AllArgsConstructor` it must create a constructor for all your fields, those annotated with `@Value` and those that aren't.

Now Lombok doesn't even know anything about `@Value` annotation of spring. So the generated constructor looks something like this:

```
public AdServiceImpl(AdRepository repository, FileService fileService, Integer DEFAULT_PageSize, String AD_IMAGE_PATH, String AD_IMAGE_URL) {
   this.repository = repository;
   ....
}
```

You can run Delombok to see the actually generated code.

Spring on the other hand when sees a single constuctor tries to call it to create the bean (`AdServiceImpl`) in this case, and only *after that* iterates through its fields and inject data annotated by `@Value`.

Now, when spring calls the constructor, it sees an integer (DEFAULT_PageSize), has no clue that its a value  (and spring has to inject something brcause its a constructor injection), and throws an Exception.

So in terms of resolution:

Don't use all args constructor of lombok in this case and instead create a non-lombok constructor for `AdRepository` and `FileService` only)

Alternatively create a constructor with @Value annotated parameters instead of field injection (remove @Value on fields):

```
public AdServiceImpl(AdRepository repository, FileService fileService, @Value(${app.ad.DefaultPageSize}"} Integer DEFAULT_PageSize, @Value(...) String AD_IMAGE_PATH, @Value(...) String AD_IMAGE_URL) {
   this.repository = repository;
   ....
}
```

Comment: Even better, use `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 1):

Add to projeck lombok.config file with this lines:

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
```

Comment: 08-06-2023, this answer is still relevant This should be at the top!

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is that you are using Lombok **@AllArgsConstructor** while some of the properties are populated by **@Value(..)**.

Replace the @AllArgsConstructor with **@RequiredArgsConstructor** and give it a try.

**Note:** Adding this comment for future references.